# If a spirit is to "return to its body" and the body is in stasis, what happens?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics, time, spirits

Can a manifester that has separated body and spirit, such as by the power *Stealsteel* or by some other means, still return to its body if the manifester's body is in stasis, such as by the power *Quintessence* or by some other method of stasis?

Comment: Don't know about other forms of stasis, but quintessence in amounts large enough to immerse an entire person in close proximity to the manifester's body would probably mess with the stealsteal to the point that it would fail before they could be fully immersed anyway since *"...accumulations of quintessence weighing 1 pound or more hinder psionic activity within a 5-foot radius of the accumulation..."* according to your source

Comment: I've been puzzling over this question for days. Man, the *steelsteal* power is *so* vague. Has the DM ruled as to what happens if the spirit's killed? Has the DM ruled that when the spirit returns, it must physically (sort of) travel the distance back to the body and hop in? Has the DM ruled that the spirit's return restores the manifester to consciousness? Has the DM ruled on how conditions on the returning spirit impact the body? Because the *steelsteal* power address none of them, and they're all at least kind of important to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The books certainly aren’t going to define this.

But it seems to me that a spirit, once immersed fully within *quintessence*, would also be subject to the time-freezing effect. That means the spirit attempts to return to the body, gets into the *quintessence*, and freezes there, unable to complete the journey. When and if the *quintessence* is removed, the spirit continues and reunites with its body just as though there had been no *quintessence* in the first place and no time had passed—which is precisely what the experience is like for the spirit.

If the “returning” is instantaneous, then the creature is still frozen within the *quintessence*. There is a quasi-philosophical/semantic argument about whether or not the spirit is now combined within the body, and whether that means something about an object frozen in *quintessence* has changed (which should be impossible), and under the game rules there may be significance to this if so, but we do not have nearly enough information to go on to really come down on one side or the other here. I would probably argue something like “even if it’s instantaneous, any externally-measurable effect of the rejoining does not happen instantaneously and so the body still, to an outside observer, appears as it did before, without its spirit.”

I would limit this answer, if it weren’t already obvious, by pointing out that *quintessence* has a lot of unknowns with it, and without knowing exactly what effect we’re talking about here, it’s really hard to say much of anything.